# bootstrap Input group class is not working

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Input group class of bootstrap is not working fine below image is the ouput of code 2nd image is desired output input group working fine for span but for button it is not working

[image: this is my output]
[image: desired output]

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<div id="Other_container" hidden>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mention your goal">
        <%--<span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer" disabled>Go!</span>--%>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
                </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change `<span class="input-group-btn">` to `<span class="input-group-addon">`

Comment: hi, i've tried to reproduce your issue... but as you can see it works well: http://www.bootply.com/KLiHfe0VLw

Comment: btw. what are you trying with <%-- [...] --%> ?